# How to filter an Array of Objects inside another Array of Objects in JavaScript (es6)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, filter

I need to filter `dogs` and also the `sitters` **inside** this Array based on another Array `sittersSelected`. (It's ok to use es6). The problem for me is handling the **nested** array.

Not sure if it's possible but...

#### Data

```
dogs = [
  {
    name: 'Alice',
    sex: 'Female',
    breed: 'German Shepherd',
    sitters: [
      {
        id: '123',
        name: 'Abby'
      },
      {
        id: '456',
        name: 'Manny'
      },
      {
        id: '789',
        name: 'Mel'
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Buckley',
    sex: 'Male',
    breed: 'Border Collie',
    sitters: [
      {
        id: '321',
        name: 'Gustavo'
      },
      {
        id: '654',
        name: 'Tommy'
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Bear',
    sex: 'Male',
    breed: 'Mixed',
    sitters: [
      {
        id: '123',
        name: 'Abby'
      },
      {
        id: '135',
        name: 'Owen'
      },
    ]
  },
];

sittersSelected = ["Abby","Manny"];
```

#### Expected Output

```
filterResult = [
  {
    name: 'Alice',
    sex: 'Female',
    breed: 'German Shepherd',
    sitters: [
      {
        id: '123',
        name: 'Abby'
      },
      {
        id: '456',
        name: 'Manny'
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Bear',
    sex: 'Male',
    breed: 'Mixed',
    sitters: [
      {
        id: '123',
        name: 'Abby'
      },
    ]
  },
];
```

#### I've tried

`filterResult = dogs.filter(dog => dog.sitters.some(sitter => sittersSelected.includes(sitter.name)));`

I managed to filter the `dogs` but not the `sitters`. Also tried other examples here on StackOverflow. Is there a way to do it? maybe with `.map()` ?

Thank you

Comment: How big can these two lists potentially be at their largest size?

Comment: @TobiahRex It is quite big, the data has more options... I just used `dogs` as an example.

Answer (score 1):

1-use map to return new object contain only filtered sitters

2-use filter to return only dog have sitters

```
let dogs = [{ name: 'Alice', sex: 'Female', breed: 'German Shepherd', sitters: [{ id: '123', name: 'Abby' }, { id: '456', name: 'Manny' }, { id: '789', name: 'Mel' },] }, { name: 'Buckley', sex: 'Male', breed: 'Border Collie', sitters: [{ id: '321', name: 'Gustavo' }, { id: '654', name: 'Tommy' },] }, { name: 'Bear', sex: 'Male', breed: 'Mixed', sitters: [{ id: '123', name: 'Abby' }, { id: '135', name: 'Owen' },] },];

let sittersSelected = ["Abby", "Manny"];

dogs.map(dog => {
    return {
        ...dog,
        sitters: dog.sitters.filter(sitter => sittersSelected.includes(sitter.name))
    }
}).filter(dog => dog.sitters.length > 0);
```

Comment: It worked, thank you so much @ProSheta

Answer (score 0):

You'll need 2 steps.

1. First filter each `sitters` sub-array to include only the ones selected.
2. Filter out the parent array items by whether the `sitters` array contains any elements:

```js
const dogs=[{name:"Alice",sex:"Female",breed:"German Shepherd",sitters:[{id:"123",name:"Abby"},{id:"456",name:"Manny"},{id:"789",name:"Mel"}]},{name:"Buckley",sex:"Male",breed:"Border Collie",sitters:[{id:"321",name:"Gustavo"},{id:"654",name:"Tommy"}]},{name:"Bear",sex:"Male",breed:"Mixed",sitters:[{id:"123",name:"Abby"},{id:"135",name:"Owen"}]}];

const sittersSelected = ["Abby","Manny"];

for (const dog of dogs) {
  dog.sitters = dog.sitters.filter(s => sittersSelected.includes(s.name));
}
const filteredDogs = dogs.filter(
  dog => dog.sitters.length
);
console.log(filteredDogs);
```

If you don't want to mutate the input array of objects, you can map it first to clone each `dog`.

Comment: Thanks @CertainPerformance it worked well. But as you suggest, I'm using `map()` to avoid mutating the array.